# Matching, merging, finding duplicated value in R

Tags: r, matrix, merge, match, duplicate-data

In R, I want to match and merge two matrices.

For example,

```
> A
     ID   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
  1  ex   3  8  7  6  9  8  4
  2  am   7  5  3  0  1  8  3
  3  ple  8  5  7  9  2  3  1

> B
    col1
  1  a
  2  c
  3  e
  4  f
```

Then, I want to match header of matrix A and 1st column of matrix B.

So I did

```
> C<-A[, c('ID', B[, 1])]
```

and the final result was like below.

```
> C
     ID   a  c  e  f
  1  ex   3  7  9  8
  2  am   7  3  1  8
  3  ple  8  7  2  3
```

However, if the matrix B has some values that are not in the matrix A like below,

```
> B
    col1
  1  a
  2  c
  3  e
  4  f
  5  x
  6  y
```

It says 'subscript out of bounds'.

How can I avoid this problem?

(How to extract duplicated columns only?)

Comment: If you really are using matrices and not data.frames, please demonstrate it by making your question reproducible. Guidance here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/1191259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
C<-A[, c('ID', colnames(A)[colnames(A) %in% B[,1]])]
```

Comment: I think `intersect(colnames(A), B[,1])` is more natural.